# How to put values of different template argument value but same type in variable of this type? C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a values of one type but different template arguments. And I want to have some variable which can store all of these values.

For example. I have a class `A` with template:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
}
```

And I have a bunch of values of type `A` but different template argument:

```
A<int> aIntVar;
A<char> aCharVar;
A<bool> aBoolVar;
```

So I want to be able to put pointers to each of them in

```
std::vector< /*pointer to some type that can store values above*/ > vectorOfAValues;
```

Like this:

```
vectorOfAValues.emplace_back(&aIntVar);
vectorOfAValues.emplace_back(&aCharVar);
vectorOfAValues.emplace_back(&aBoolVar);
```

But I can't because types of these values are not polymorphic to their template-argumentless type.

Roughly speaking I want to make polymorphism among family of types that's made of one type but with different template argument.

Comment: *"I have a bunch of values of type A"* - you have a bunch of values of different, unrelated types `A<int>`, `A<char>`, `A<bool>`. Pointers to them are different unrelated types as well. `std::vector` is a homogeneous container, that is all stored values must have the same type. So it is not possible to store these values or pointers to them in a single vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
struct BaseA { ... };

template <typeaname T> class A : public BaseA { ... };
```

But then you will have to store pointers to `BaseA`, preferably smart pointers.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseA>> vectorOfAValues;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseA>> vectorOfAValues;
```

Comment: This is fine, but shouldn't the real question be why do we want a collection of unrelated types to begin with?

Comment: @cplusplusrat, the need for that is well recognized. That's why you have `std::any` and `std::variant`.

Comment: In a collection? Do you have any references you can point to? I would like to better understand the use-case.

Comment: @cplusplusrat, in my domain, CAD and CAE, it's very common to have collections of mesh controls and simulation controls that can contain floating point numbers, enums, integral values, boolean values, and strings.

Comment: @cplusplusrat OP: "I want to make polymorphism among family of types". Is it the fact that `Base` looks rather empty that disturbs you? Of course anything that those types do have in common should be placed in `Base`

Comment: And then at runtime, you do a `dynamic_cast` or store the type information somewhere as well for this to be of any use? Wasn't aware of people doing this in production. For me this pattern is usually a code smell and the developer not putting any thought in the code organization. This is fine I suppose in languages that support reflection as it fits a bit more naturally. Its very cumbersome in c++ and I actively avoid it But then, I am only speaking from experience in the applications I have worked in. So cannot generalize this.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 My main issue is with the type information. On account of entirely unrelated types in the derived class, the base class cannot have any useful interface and the type information in the derived classes need to be manually handled. I would do everything I can to avoid having to maintain such a code. I have no doubts it will work. But the question is, if we can get away with reorganizing the code to avoid this pattern, would you insist on re-working it in a code review or accept it as is.

Comment: @cplusplusrat there is too little context in the question, but I can imagine lots of completely valid uses cases. They are not different from usual polymorphism. Just as example assume each type has a `std::string to_string()`. I dont think this is any more worse design than normal inheritance for runtime polymorphism

Comment: @cplusplusrat I mean I can understand your doubts, but this is the wrong place to question OPs motivation. It seems they are quite aware of what they want and this answer tells how to get there

Comment: @cplusplusrat, there are places where `dynamic_cast` must be used similar to an `if`-`else` block, but not in a cascading `if`-`else if`---- `else` fashion. It is not code smell. It is a side effect of using C++. You need specific data corresponding to leaf types where the rubber meets the road. Not everything contained in a leaf type can be abstracted away to a `virtual` function in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

On C++ 17 you can use

[std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

```
#include <any>
#include <vector>

template<class X>
class A {}

int main(int, char**) {
   std::vector<std::any> myVec {A<char>{}, A<int>{}, A<float>{}};
   return 0;
}
```

or with pointers

```
...
std::any anyA = A<int>{};
std::any anyB = A<float>{};

std::vector<std::any*> a{&anyA, &anyB};
```